# save scraped data in different dictionaries using filter condition

Tags: python, dictionary, filter, scrapy

I have scraped 2 urls from a same spider as follows:

```
 def start_requests(self):
  #calling Dawn Categories
  yield Request('https://www.dawn.com/business',callback=self.Dawn, meta={'category': 'business','source': 'DAWN'})
  yield Request('https://www.dawn.com/sport',callback=self.Dawn, meta={'category': 'sports','source': 'DAWN'})
```

where self.Dawn scrapes the news from the links as follows:

```
def parseDawn(self, response):
  items = WebscrapingItem()

  title = response.css("h2.story__title a.story__link::text").extract_first().strip() ,
  author = response.css("span.story__byline a.story__byline__link::text").extract_first() , 
  category = response.meta['category']

  items['title'] = title
  items['author'] = author
  items['category'] = category

  yield items
```

Now, in my `pipelines.py` file, I want to filter those scraped news that have `category=='business'` and `category=='sports'` in two separate dictionaries. I am doing this so that the filtered news can be saved separately in my database. Is there a way of doing this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do that using your pipeline -

```
class BotPipeline:
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if item['category'] == 'business':
            # insert db operation with this filtered item
            return item
        if item['category'] == 'sports':
            # insert db operation with this filtered item
            return item
```